# How to delay a page refresh in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> I want to refresh a web page using javascript but when any event occur after few second the page     will refresh.
>     what can i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get JavaScript to delay, and then refresh the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752696/how-do-i-get-javascript-to-delay-and-then-refresh-the-page)

Answer (score 3):

You can try `setTimeout()`

```
setTimeout(function() {
      // Do something after 5 seconds
      location.reload();//reload page
}, 5000);
```

Comment: `setTimeout` is generic JavaScript, not a jQuery-specific feature.

Answer (score 0):

Use meta tag like  `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="300">` 
This wiil make your page to refresh every 5minutes (5*60)