# How do I get JavaScript to delay, and then refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I'd like my JavaScript to, at the end of the function I have created, wait seven seconds, and then refresh my page. If it is important, I have the vital parts of my JavaScript and HTML below...

Javascript:

```
var textfill = function () {
    var node = document.createElement("P");
    var x = document.getElementById('entertext').value;
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("The search results for: '" + x + "' will show up here");
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("123").appendChild(node);
}
```

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" id="entertext">
 <input type="button" onclick="textfill()" value="Search">
 <p id="123">
 </p>
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure how to make that start once the function is finished, and how to have it trigger a refresh.

Comment: Add it at the end of the function

Comment: Well, yeah, but to have it trigger a refresh?

Comment: Have a look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854820/sleep-pause-wait-in-javascript

Comment: What you really want to do is to submit the search form, not just refresh the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function refreshPage() {
    //ensure reloading from server instead of cache
    location.reload(true);
}
function delayRefreshPage(mileSeconds) {
    window.setTimeout(refreshPage, mileSeconds);
}
var textfill = function () {
    var node = document.createElement("P");
    var x = document.getElementById('entertext').value;
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("The search results for: '" + x + "' will show up here");
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("123").appendChild(node);
    delayRefreshPage(2000);
}
```

Summarizing @ioseph and my personal experience.

Answer (score 2):

To do something after a certain amount of time use setTimeout - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

And to refresh the page, call

```
window.location.reload
```